# How To Use Voyager Widgets in a blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, voyager

How could i reuse voyager widget in any blade file
i know i could use it and re define it in dashboard  using this method in "voyager.php"

```
        'widgets' => [
        'TCG\\Voyager\\Widgets\\UserDimmer',
        'TCG\\Voyager\\Widgets\\PostDimmer',
        'TCG\\Voyager\\Widgets\\PageDimmer',
        'App\\Widgets\\whatEver0',
        'App\\Widgets\\whatEver1',
        'App\\Widgets\\whatEver2',
    ],
```

but i want to use one of this widgets in my views ('in blade.php file ')